# Deleting data in xml file not working correctly

Tags: java, xml

I am developing a XML Editor and when user clicks delete on a type the application shall delete the whole type.
but its not its only deleting the content but leaving the tags.

```
<type>
<OBJECT_TYPE/>
<prop/>
<param/>
<param/>
<param/>
<param/>
<param/>
<param/>
<param/>
<param/>
<param/>
<param/>
<param/>
<param/>
<param/>
<param/>
</type>
<type>
<OBJECT_TYPE/>
<prop/>
<param/>
<param/>
<param/>
</type>
<type>
<OBJECT_TYPE/>
<prop/>
<param/>
<param/>
</type>
```

So basiclly all the data is gone but its leaving this tags and I want to delte them aswell.
how to do it?

My code :

```
NodeList type = (NodeList) doc.getElementsByTagName("type").item(x);
            System.out.println("type : " + type);

            for (int i = 0; i < type.getLength(); i++) {

                Node curNode = (Node) type.item(i);
                System.out.println(" Node name : " + curNode.getChildNodes());
                removeChilds(curNode);

            }

            // Save the new update
            save(doc);

public static void removeChilds(Node node) {
        while (node.hasChildNodes())
            node.removeChild(node.getFirstChild());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing wrong DOM tree navigation. The `item` already returns you a `Node` for `<type>` tag. You just need to delete it:

```
Node type = doc.getElementsByTagName("type").item(x);
type.getParentNode().removeChild(type);
```

That are you doing in your code - you are casting `Node` to `NodeList` (xml elements are also list of children nodes), so your `for` loop iterates over children of the `<type>`. Then in each child (such as `prop` and `param` in your example) you iterate over children again and remove each of them. So you never delete `type` node.